# Umbraco search engine duplicate bug

Tags: search-engine, umbraco7

Hi here the scenario i created a SITE1 where in the blog it has an examine search engine and it is working correctly. now I have to copy my whole page to duplicate it for my new demo SITE2 then I test my search engine and it picked the searched item on the page it self "AND IT ALSO PICKED THE ITEM ON THE SITE1!" :/ that's bad issue..

Any idea how to avoid to picked search item on the other site or content??

Here is my search code:

```
@{

    string searchTerm = Request.QueryString["search"];
    var searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["WebsiteSearcher"];
    var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria(Examine.SearchCriteria.BooleanOperation.And);
    var query = searchCriteria.GroupedOr(new string[] { "nodeName", "addblogImage", "blogTitle", "datePublished", "blogCategory", "blogAuthor", "blogbodyText", "blogreadMore" }, searchTerm).Compile();
    var searchResults = searcher.Search(query);

}
@{
try {
if (searchResults.Any()){
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-0 row-fluid clearfix clean-list background-white">
    <div class="span4 post padding">
        @foreach (var result in searchResults){
            var node = Umbraco.Content(result.Fields["id"]);
            <div class="item column-1" itemprop="blogPost" style="margin:0">
                @if(node.HasValue("addblogImage")){
                    var blogImg = Umbraco.TypedMedia(node.GetPropertyValue<string>("addblogImage"));
                    <img src="@blogImg.Url" alt="" width="898" height="597">
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried manually rebuilding the search index?

Comment: Yes, i tried many times but i didn't hit the correct solution.

Comment: @Mark here if you need to see  the code. thanks for help

Comment: Are you sure each site uses a different IndexPath for the IndexSet?

Comment: i'm not sure, i have created only 1 indexSet

Comment: You can check ExaminIndex.config to make sure the IndexPath is relative to the filepath of both sites

Comment: @Mark now i created new indexSet, how can I include that in macro??

var searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["WebsiteSearcher"];

Comment: You can do this in de ExamineSettings.config

Comment: Yes, i already add it in de ExamineSettings.config under ExamineIndexProviders.. after that?

Comment: Also add a search with the same name and then you can use the searcher in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like both sites use the same search index.

Make sure in ExamineIndex.config the indexers are using a different IndexPath

For more useful Examine documentation, check out: http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/9/16/examining-examine